# How to remove text from "/" to the end of the text?

Tags: jquery

I have this dynamic text `pluto.co/bf4d4ce3-c2b9-4e77-8adb-925f5adf927a`, I want to remove with jquery the code between slash and the end of text.

I tried with the following:

```
var div = $("div.text");
div.text(div.text().trim().replace("/bf4d4ce3-c2b9-4e77-8adb-925f5adf927a", ""));
```

But doesn't work because the text changes when I refresh the page.

Comment: jQuery is a DOM manipulation library, not a text library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without regex:

```
var tmpString = div.text().trim().split('/');
tmpString.pop();
div.text(tmpString.join(''));
```

Comment: Your answer is the fastest I've ever received on StackOverflow. Thank you so much @antyrat!!

Answer (score 0):

Use. Split() then remove the last part of array